# Функция даты, метод getSeconds()

Tags: javascript, дата

Нужна функция, которая выводит текущее значение секунд, через метод .getSeconds(), но в формате 2 цифр. Метод то toLocaleDateString(), по какой то причине не взаимодействует с .getSeconds(). Как решить проблему не используя toLocaleDateString() и не проверяя каждый раз значение секунд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понял вопрос, но если вам нужно сохранить ведущие нули, то можно использовать slice -

```js
setInterval(() => console.log(
  ('00'+(new Date()).getSeconds()).slice(-2)
), 1000);
```